# NSURLSessionConfiguration and NSData always returning nil

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, nsurlsession, macos-mojave, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I am new to Mac application development and i am working on fixing the deprecation issues present in the application. I am using XCode 11.3 in Mojave MacOS 10.14 and Our application contains the following line of code

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResonse:response error:Error]
```

A warning message getting displayed as `sendSynchronousRequest` is deprecated and it is suggesting to use `[NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:]` .

so i have implemented the following code

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue    mainQueue]];
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"MyURLHere"];
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];    
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                      NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                      if(error == nil)
                                      {
                                          NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                      }
                                  }];
[dataTask resume];
```

i found that `data` is being returned as `nil` always. When i debugged the code, i found that even `[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]` is being returned as `nil`. Can you please suggest what needs to be done in order to fix these issues?

Comment: When i declare NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession]; and check the value of sesion then it  is being returned as nil .. What is causing to return nil always for this line of code?

Comment: @Rob Yes i am using connection that starts with https:// only

Comment: @Rob Even i have checked the following simple code but still the data is returned as nil  

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
 NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                         completionHandler:
     ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
         // ...
     }];

 [task resume];

Comment: There’s not enough here to answer your question. And you haven’t answered the clarification questions (have you turned on outbound connections in the project capabilities tab? What were `response` and `error` objects? Where are you printing the `data`?)

Comment: @Rob I am new to this development process so i am in search of these settings. Can you please tell me the exact location where can i find the outbound connections ?

Comment: I have [moved this discussion to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218366/discussion-between-rob-and-kamal).